# How to wrap React Router v4's NavLink component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to figure out how to wrap React Router v4's `NavLink` component to set a default `activeClassName`.

However, `props` is undefined.

Wrapper:

```
const Test = ({children, props}) => {
  console.log(children) // Blackboard
  console.log(props) // undefined
  return (
    <NavLink activeClassName="active" {...props}>
      {children}
    </NavLink>
  )
}
```

Use:

```
<Test to='/blackboard'>Blackboard</Test>
```

Why is `children` populated, but `props` **undefined**?

**Update:**

When using `to` instead of `props`, it works.

`const Test = ({children, to}) => {`

However, I'm not sure why `props` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I understand it now.

`const Test = ({children, to}) => {`

`children` and `to` are destructured from `props`.

This works:

```
const Test = props => 
  <NavLink activeClassName='active' {...props}>
    {props.children}
  </NavLink>
```

Comment: Sorry I made some assumptions about the syntax you were using since you were using Router v4. I _would_ pluck the `children` prop, or explicitly pass `to` to the NavLink if you're not using other props, so that you're not passing the `children` prop to the NavLink.

Comment: @Andy_D, I'm glad you did since I now understand a bit more than I did before.  Would you happen to have any opinions/resources on best practices for React components?